# 2 sided vs 1 sided test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, proportion

I am asking this questions straight from "Data Analysis and Statistical Inference " course
by Dr. Mine Çetinkaya-Rundel on coursera! Please right click on the image and one in a new tab to make it bigger.[image]

In below example, can we do one sided hypothesis test? i want to find out if Streptomycin is effective or not. Based upon histogram, only 1 out of of 100 observations has chance of having >0.2 probability. 0.2 = (51/55)-(38/52).

For some reason the professor is doing two sided test. I want to perform one sided test as i just dont want to say that both treatments are different, but i also want to prove that Streptomycin is better.

Comment: We have no evidence whether the drug is efficacious or deleterious to health. If we find that the drug is deleterious, such a finding is indeed "significant" so we want a test that is powered to detect that, and thus prevent harming any more subjects with unnecessary further experimentation.

Comment: i am still not clear, I got your point that a finding that the drug has harmful effects is "significant". but lets say i want to prove that drug is better then what changes should i make to my sample size or to histogram?

Comment: The histogram, which depicts the sampling distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis, is unaffected by a 1-sided versus 2-sided specification of the test. It only affects the critical values in which you would call evidence "inconsistent with the null". Likewise, you don't change the sample size. You simply use the basic knowledge of probability and statistics to find a cut-off s.t. evidence is deemed inconsistent with the null hypothesis (at an $\alpha$-level) for a value exceeding a threshold (and corresponding $\alpha$ probability).

Comment: okay i got that histogram and sample size will remain the same. But lets say i am the scientist who invented that drug and i want to prove not only that my drug is different than current system but also that my drug is better than current system...cannot i prove that with this data?

Comment: of course, you can conduct a 1 sided test. Or you can conduct a 2-sided test and, if the direction of the effect suggests a benefit due to the drug, you can infer that the drug is helpful. It's a big mistake to think that, when you reject the null hypothesis from a 2-sided test, all that you know is that, "the effect is at least different from 0". In practice, you can make two types of decisions based on significant findings from a 2 sided test.

Comment: in case of above data, lets begin with 2 sided test and 99% level of confidence: would we say that we fail to reject null hypothesis as there is one point above 0.2 and and one point below -0.2, therefore 2 out of 100 data points happen just by chance? but if we go for 1 sided test where alternative hypothesis is that the new drug is better then we would reject the null hypothesis as there is only 1 point above 0.2%?

Comment: In summary, two sided test tells us that there is not enough evidence to reject null hypothesis that both treatments are similar. But one sided test tells us that there is enough evidence to reject null hypothesis that both treatments are similar..aren't we getting contradictory results?

Comment: any reply? Please let me know

Comment: Maybe you should reframe that as a new question.